# Execute Process with a path containing address

Tags: java, shell

I am using `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` to execute a command through Java, but I am having problem regarding path (with spaces) to run the command.

I have enclose the path with `"` (double-quotes) and also tried with `'` (single-quotes), but failed...:(:(:(

**My code is :**

```
private void encryptFile(String csvFilePath) throws IOException {
    Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("gpg --recipient testKey2014 --output '" + csvFilePath + ".gpg' --encrypt '" + csvFilePath + "'");
    try {
        proc.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

    String s = null;
    if (stdInput.ready()) {
        // read the output from the command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    if (stdError.ready()) {
        // read any errors from the attempted command
        System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried same String in my terminal and it is executing fine, but here since the `csvFilePath` containing (space), that's why the command is not working.

The actual command is :

```
gpg --recipient testKey2014 --output '/home/avis/testDir/File Transfers/Recordings/PH2014050401/PH2014050401.zip.gpg' --encrypt '/home/avis/testDir/File Transfers/Recordings/PH2014050401/PH2014050401.zip'
```

OUTPUT is :

```
Here is the standard error of the command (if any):

usage: gpg [options] [filename]
```

Anyone suggest what to do???

Comment: is there something in java like **verbatim-string-literal:** `@"verbatim -string-literal"` in C#

Comment: No, there is no verbatim string in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [array version of exec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29):

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"gpg",
                                                      "--recipient",
                                                      "testKey2014",
                                                      "--output",
                                                      csvFilePath + ".gpg",
                                                      "--encrypt"
                                                      csvFilePath});
```